# Load videoplayer only when creative exist

Tags: media-player, google-ad-manager, video-ads

I created a Ad unit for video in Google AdManager. Manual is here: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1181016?hl=en.
I used generated AdTagUrl in my Radiant Player (I want to use it for video advertisement included to article). Manual is here: https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/docs/latest/outstream-video-ads.html.
It's working OK. But only when AdManager sends a creative. When AdManager sends no creative, I must hide the player.

Is there a way to detect, if AdManager sends a creative before loading the player?

For example something like:

```
function showOutstreamVideo()
{
    //detect if there is an advertisement
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", AdTagUrl, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    {
        var vast = x.responseXML;
        if(vast.getElementsByTagName("Ad").length>0)
        {   //code for read, init and place player
        }
  }
}
```

...but I cannot init Radiant Player with this vast object. And when I use adTagUrl again, for AdManager it'll be second impression, that can be different.
Is there a solution to prevent the page from unnecessarily requesting the player script, when there is no creative?

Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the Radiant Player dynamically?

```js
var settings = {};
var vast = x.responseXML;
if(vast.getElementsByTagName("Ad").length>0) {
    var player = document.createElement('script');
    player.src = "https://cdn.radiantmediatechs.com/rmp/5.10.6/js/rmp.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(player);
    var elementID = 'rmpPlayer';
    var rmp = new RadiantMP(elementID);
    rmp.init(settings);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I load player dynamically, but how to get the player to pick up an already loaded vast object (document) instead of second request to adTagUrl?

Comment: I'm working with JW Player rather than the Radiant Player. It is possible to load VAST XML's (rather than ad tag URLs) directly via API. Probably the Radiant Player doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

AdResponse: vast, (as string) was the right choice in player setting.

```
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", outstreamAdTagUrl, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {   if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
        {   vast = x.responseText; //x.responeXML;
            //if(vast.getElementsByTagName("Ad").length>0)
            if(vast.length > 200) //it should be sufficient to determine if it is an ad or an empty VAST
            {   //read and init player
                var player = document.createElement('script');
                document.body.appendChild(player);
                player.onload = function(){runOutstream(vast);};
                player.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.radiantmediatechs.com/rmp/5.10.6/js/rmp.min.js');
            }
        }
    };
    x.send(null);

    function runOutstream(vast)
    {
    var settings = {
        ... license key etc...
        autoplay: true,
        adOutStreamMutedAutoplay: true,
        ads: true,
        //adsResponse: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(vast), //when using responseXML()
        adsResponse: vast,
        adOutStream: true,
        skin: 'outstream',
        ...other setting
    };

    var rmp = new RadiantMP('rmpPlayer');
    rmp.init(settings);
    }
```